# Debug log Winter '16 release

Tags: debug

I have used debug log of previous releases. But the **winter '16 release debug** log has new terms like ***Traced Entity*** and ***Debug Level***. Help for this page does not give much clarity.

[image]

can you help me out with this???

Comment: Hello...you can refer the similar question which I had posted a month ago . http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92771/what-is-debug-level-in-new-salesforce-edition